# Check if a string contains number or is numeric - Thymeleaf

Tags: regex, string, thymeleaf, isnumeric

Is there a way to check if string is numeric.
`{#strings.isNumeric(dataField)}` doesn't work.

How can I check if string contains numbers (specific number of digits as well) - is there a RegEx that can be used, or an inbuilt function that can be called?

Want to avoid this below:

```
{#string.contains('1') or #string.contains('2')}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `matches()`:

```
{#dataField.matches('[0-9]{3,8}')}
```

This matches a string that is from 3 to 8 digits long (inclusive). You can change those values to whatever works for you.

You can also use open-ended length ranges: `[0-9]{3,}` means "at least 3 digits"

Comment: For some reason this is not working testStringResult = ${#strings.matches(testString, '[0-9]')}

Comment: Error: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 9): Method call: Method matches(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) cannot be found on org.thymeleaf.expression.Strings type
 at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:273)

Comment: @loser I'm not familiar with thymeleaf, but try my edited code

Answer (score 1):

If you have in your path the library `org.apache.commons.lang3` you could use it as next

```
${T(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils).isNumeric(dataField)}
```

So in case you want to use an if block it would be:

```
<th:block th:if="${T(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils).isNumeric(dataField)}">
   <p>Is numeric!</p>
</th:block/>
```

---

Otherwise, if you don't have `org.apache.commons.lang3` in your classpath you could implement your own method which checks if it is numeric and then use it.
So you could create a class like next:

```
package your.package;

public class Utils {
     public static boolean isNumeric(String data){
           //impl
           return true;
     }
}
```

And then use it the next expression:

```
${T(your.package.Utils).isNumeric(dataField)}
```