# How to check if a string matches with regex in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm writing a training application to collect books on the following stack: Java/Spring/Thymeleaf.

I should input some values about books such as a book title and a book size (a number of pages).

Validation fields in dto class Book:

```
@NotEmpty
private String title;
@NotNull
@Digits(integer = 4, fraction = 0)
private Integer size;
```

The view file contains:

```
 <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="book_title" th:field="*{title}">
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors()} and *{title}==''">field title must not be empty</p>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="size (page)" th:field="*{size}">
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors()} and !${#size.matches('[0-9]{1,4}')}">field value must be digit and less than 4 signs</p>
```

It works properly: if the `title` field is not filled we can see the message.
However, for the `size` field we expect 4 digits, but how to configure this regex correctly? `!${#size.matches('[0-9]{1,4}')}` in this way there is no warning message.

I have foung the simillar question
[Check if a string contains number or is numeric - Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072931/check-if-a-string-contains-number-or-is-numeric-thymeleaf)
But I need to invert boolean condition and it dooes not work for my case

Comment: I write my regex according to this link and invert boolen expression but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which field has errors in the Thymeleaf template when calling `hasErrors()` function.

Something like this:

```
<p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('size')}">field value must be digit and less than 4 signs</p>
```

This way the error is shown only when the `size` field has errors and you don't need to use the regex to check its value.